# How to backup files and folders using ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a folder of files and sub folders with some template files which needs to be deployed in a remote machine, but before deploying these files & folders I need to backup these in the control system (where ansible is running). The number of files which needs to be deployed is not fixed, it might change. Is it possible to do this in ansible?

Below is my ansible configuration and global variable file which works till extract step.

```
---
#Global vars
aws_access_key: xxx
aws_secret_key: xxx
aws_bucket: s3-artifacts
aws_bucket_download: /deployment/trial/deployment.tar.gz
local_download: deployment.tar.gz
current_dir: /root/tools/deployment/trial/
local_extract_dir: extracted

deployment_usr: root
deployment_grp: root
mode: 775
...




---
- hosts: web
  tasks:
   - name: Download from S3
     s3: aws_access_key="{{ aws_access_key }}" aws_secret_key="{{ aws_secret_key }}" bucket="{{ aws_bucket }}" object="{{ aws_bucket_download }}" dest="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_download }}" mode=get overwrite=true
   #Change permissions
   - name: Change permissions
     file: path="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_download }}" owner="{{ deployment_usr }}" group="{{ deployment_grp }}" mode="{{ mode }}"
   #Extract
   - name: mkdir local_extract_dir
     file: path="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_extract_dir }}" state=directory mode="{{ mode }}"
   - name: Extracting deployment folder 
     unarchive: src="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_download }}" dest="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_extract_dir }}"
   - name: Give permissions
     file: path="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_extract_dir }}" owner="{{ deployment_usr }}" group="{{ deployment_grp }}" mode="{{ mode }}"

   #Backup
   #- name: Synchronize
     #synchronize: src="{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_extract_dir }}"

...
```

I  also tried running `(cd extracted; find .) | cut -c 3-` command which gives the list of extracted files and folders but need help in taking backup of these files from remote machine.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) module:

```
- name: Copy some directory
  copy:
    src: "{{ current_dir }}/{{ local_extract_dir }}/"
    dest: "{{ backup_dir }}/"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Also take a look at the [synchronize module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) if you prefer a rsync based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html

```
- name: Specifying a path directly
  fetch:
    src: /tmp/somefile
    dest: /tmp/prefix-{{ inventory_hostname }}
    flat: yes
```